# Transparent Background with Opaque Widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a question. I am new to Flutter. Is it possible in Flutter to have a completely transparent background with some opaque widgets? For example, we have a red flat button with on a completely transparent background?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Colors.transparent` color that you can use as backgound in many widgets.

Comment: Yeah I came across that. I used that on my root widget. However, the child widgets do not show up anymore in that case !!

Comment: You know I found a solution. If we use Opacity widget first and other widgets as the children it would work. I will copy my sample work !

Comment: Good to know you found a solution!